# Working with pre emptive VMs on Google Compute Engine

Tags: elasticsearch, google-compute-engine, autoscaling

I'm trying to work with multiple Pre-emptive VM instances on Google Compute Engine for elastic search service and facing some doubts as follows:-

1. Is 30sec window enough to store data from a preemptive elastic search instance to a stable VM?
2. How to save the state of one VM that is ending and restore it to other?
3. Is there an alternative to Google Autoscaler?

Comment: Try StackExchange or another forum dedicated to elasticsearch, this is not really a question specific to GCE (it's just that Preemptible VMs gives you the 30s criteria that you're asking about).

Comment: @PaulR.Nash well, if the question is about general hibernation and wake up of the preemptive (Linux) machine, then it's more about GCE than Elasticsearch.

Comment: It says "is 30sec enough to store data..." So, it would depend on the data and the application, wouldn't it?

Comment: I 've rather posted a separate question to clarify my idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974562/google-compute-engine-suspend-and-restore-preemptible-machine-to-disk

Answer (score 0):

You could try running a ['shutdown-script'](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript) to create a snapshot with the command:

gcloud compute disks snapshot [disk_name] --zone=[zone] --snapshot-names=[snapshot_name]

Although you should manage to have different snapshot names. Using this you would have a backup of the current VM state, but there is no automatic way to create another VM from this snapshot when is created.

As far as I know there is no predefined alternative that do the same as the autoscaler. Although you could also try using the shutdown script to starts a VM.